# Tikz drawing objects/figures on Pythagorean diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am a mathematics teacher, and I have to make many tests using Pythagoras, kite in a tree, attached by string, a boat out to sea, etc. I would like to know the best ways of drawing these pictures do I need to learn another program?
MWE.
I have now tried inkscape obtained an SVG file, by using trace Bitmap, not a very good result, or I couldn't use it well. Tried Gimp 2.10.14 got a better result, was able to manipulate image. Would still like to know how these images are created.I have also got all the Tikz people, thank you  Nils Fleischhacker.

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \sbox0{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Green_Tree}}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\wd0/400, y=\ht0/400]
    
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0){\usebox0};
    \draw[blue, ultra thick, |-|] (275,0) -- (275,400);
        \draw[blue, ultra thick, |-|] (220,0) -- (-200,0);
            \draw[blue, ultra thick, |-|] (-210,30) -- (240,400);
\node [below] at (0,0)   {\textbf {\LARGE {4 m}}};
\node [right] at (300,150)   {\textbf {\LARGE {13 m}}}; 
\node [left ] at (-25,220 )   {\textbf {\LARGE {$x \, m$}}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://ipe.otfried.org/) help you.